# Converting string from buffered reader to double

Tags: java

my assignment requires me to create an program to read an text file and calculate the values in there. The text file contain something like this :

```
"11047461 [tab] 60.5

 12024121 [tab] 58

 12027019 [tab] 33"
```

the 8 numbers infront is ignore, only the numbers at the back are calculated.

after refering to some codings from this web.I still get a message like this :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "11047461 60.5"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
    at Problem2.main(Problem2.java:16)
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\My World\\Downloads\\PRG102D.txt")));

    String line;
    double score;

    while((line = read.readLine()) != null) {
    score = Double.parseDouble(line);
    System.out.println(score);


}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only want to parse the part of the line that contains the String representation of the double value.  As it is, you're parsing the entire line without ignoring the first number.

Comment: is there any way to do so??i only know how to cancel it using array

Comment: @TziyhiChoo You can use [`String#split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) **OR** use [`Scanner Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: @TziyhiChoo Look at the methods on the String class

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you didn't parse the line, so it tries to decode the entire line to a double, and it can't.

here's something you can do :

```
while((line = read.readLine()) != null) 
    {
    score = Double.parseDouble(line.subString(lastIndexOf(' ')+1));
    System.out.println(score);
    }
```

Comment: This assumes the tab is composed of spaces rather than the tabulator character.

Comment: no, it doesn't have anything to do with the tab character. i saw a space after it, so it belongs to it. anyway, he can put anything in the "lastIndexOf" function that fits his needs.